# Solving probability problems with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, probability, montecarlo

How can I simulate this question using MATLAB?

> Out of 100 apples, 10 are rotten. We randomly choose 5 apples without
> replacement. What is the probability that there is at least one
> rotten?

The Expected Answer

> 0.4162476

My Attempt:

```matlab
r=0
for i=1:10000
    for c=1:5
        a = randi(1,100);
        if a < 11
            r=r+1;
        end
    end
end
r/10000
```

but it didn't work, so what would be a better way of doing it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the answer that your code returns

Answer (score 2):

Use [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to choose randomly without replacement:

```
A = false(1, 100);
A(1:10) = true;
r = 0;

for k = 1:10000
  a = randperm(100, 5);
  r = r + any(A(a));
end

result = r/10000;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

Your problem follow an [hypergeometric distribution](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/hypergeometric-distribution.html) (similar to a binomial distribution but without replacement), if you have the necessary toolbox you can simply use the probability density function of the hypergeometric distribution:

```
r = 1-hygepdf(0,100,10,5) % r = 0.4162
```

Since `P(x>=1) = P(x=1) + P(x=2) + P(x=3) + P(x=4) + P(x=5) = 1-P(x=0)`

Of course, here I calculate the exact probability, this is not an experimental result.

---

**To get further:**

Noticed that if you do not have access to `hygepdf`, you can easily write the function yourself by using binomial coefficient:

```
N = 100; K = 10; 
n = 5;   k = 0;
r = 1-(nchoosek(K,k)*nchoosek(N-K,n-k))/nchoosek(N,n) % r = 0.4162
```

You can also use the binomial probability density function, it is a bit more tricky (but also more intuitive):

```
r = 1-prod(binopdf(0,1,10./(100-[0:4])))
```

Here we compute the probability to obtain 0 rotten apple five time in a row, the probabily increase at every step since we remove 1 good juicy apple each time. And then, according to the above explaination, we take `1-P(x=0)`.

Comment: Or `1-prod((90-(0:4))./(100-(0:4)))`. This is of course equivalent to the expression with `binopdf`, but I find it more intuitive

Comment: Indeed this is even a better approach !

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code. First of all, implicitly in what you wrote, you replace the apple after you look at it. When you generate the random number, you need to eliminate the possibility of choosing that number again.

I've rewritten your code to include better practices:

```
clear

n_runs = 1000;
success = zeros(n_runs, 1);
failure = zeros(n_runs, 1);
approach = zeros(n_runs, 1);

for ii = 1:n_runs
    apples = 1:100;
    a = randperm(100, 5);
    if any(a < 11)
        success(ii) = 1;
    elseif a >= 11
        failure(ii) = 1;
    end
    approach(ii) = sum(success)/(sum(success)+sum(failure));
end

figure; hold on
plot(approach)
title("r = "+ approach(end))
hold off
```

The results are stored in an array (called `approach`), rather than a single number being updated every time, which means you can see how quickly you approach the end value of `r`.

Another good habit is including `clear` at the beginning of any script, which reduces the possibility of an error occurring due to variables stored in the workspace.

Comment: A credit to @rahnema1 for mentioning the use of `randperm`, I hadn't heard of this before.